# Lucene 3.6.2 and Pulsing codec

Tags: java, lucene

I would like to use the Lucene's PulsingCodec on some of the fields of my index but i don't know how to force Lucene using such codec.
How can i do?
Are there any bugs with the Pulsing codec and Lucene 3.6.2?

[Lucene's PulsingCodec on "Primary Key" Fields](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2010/06/lucenes-pulsingcodec-on-primary-key.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ignore the bits in parentheses.  From the article:

> now available on trunk, which will eventually be the next major release, 4.0

It was not released for 3.6.  I believe it was available before the release of 4.0 ALPHA, on the development trunk.  If you need it, upgrade to Lucene 4.X.